# Meteor userId cleared on browser navigation (using react-router)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-router

After setting the userId for the Meteor connection (with "this.setUserId" in a Meteor method on the server), when the user refreshes the page or manually types in a URL, the userId for the connection is getting cleared (set to null).  Is this expected behavior?  Do I need to persist the userId in the session or something?

I'm using react and react-router.

I'm not using the accounts or accounts-password packages.  I suppose I could...  Would that fix the problem I'm having?

Comment: did my answer help you with your accounts issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Would that fix the problem I'm having?**

Yes

**I'm not using the accounts or accounts-password packages.**

Using accounts is the usual way to have a working user system in Meteor. At least you have a secure and reliable user management out of the box.

Once the user is logged in, Meteor automatically manages this.userId() and meteor.user() for the current user.

**I suppose I could...**

Yes you can integrate your own user management system or use several other packages, but the integration to Meteor's functionality is then completely up to you.

**Regarding React-Router**

It should not interfere with the account system of meteor, so you can safely integrate accounts-password